# Offline Maps, Markers, lines in Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, maps

I want to create an app for both platforms - Android and iOS. The requirement is to display a map - not compulsory a detailed map with all roads, places.. just outline of distrcits is fine. It's limited to 4 districts as of now.

So I'm also fine with image of map being displayed.

Now, I need to place markers at few places displaying hubs and lines between those hubs. On clicking upon those hubs or lines, it will display details about it.

Now, I am facing trouble researching on this. I also tried chatGPT but couldn't generate anything helpful. I just need a direction to search with so that I will research with perticular library, technology etc.